# Visual Studio templating - conditionally hide parameter

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-templates

I am attempting to create a custom Visual Studio project template and I have a template.json. What I am trying to achieve is to hide / disable the `DoStuff` parameter from the Visual Studio create project wizard if another parameter (in my case, `ProjectType`) was equal to something specific. It would essentially be something like the `Docker OS` parameter from the default Visual Studio API template.

[image: VS create project wizard]

As you can see, by default the dropdown (in my case, it would be a checkbox) is hidden / disabled, but if I check `Enable Docker`, it can be selected.

Below is my current `template.json` file which I can't seem to get right to have this feature.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "symbols": {
      "ProjectType": {
        "type": "parameter",
        "datatype": "choice",
        "choices": [
          {
            "choice": "Console"
          },
          {
            "choice": "API"
          }
        ],
        "defaultValue": "API",
        "description": "The type of the project you are building."
      },
      "DoStuff": {
        "type": "parameter",
        "datatype": "bool",
        "defaultValue": "false",
        // hide if ProjectType == API
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to combine it with `ide.host.json` to achieve this, but it's not working at all.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/ide.host.json",
    "defaultSymbolVisibility": true,
    "order": 2,
    "icon": "icon.png",
    "symbolInfo": [
      {
        "id": "DoStuff",
        "isVisible": "(ProjectType == \"API\")"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation and contacting Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi (sayedihashimi) [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ArmanOssiLoko/status/1573047866012344320), it turns out this is currently not supported and there's likely no way to achieve it right now in .NET 6 and prior releases.

However, as per Chet Husk's (@ChetHusk) template engine upgrades comment (which redirects you to Github:[dotnet/templating/docs/Conditions.md](https://github.com/dotnet/templating/blob/main/docs/Conditions.md#conditional-parameters)), templating conditions will be a feature added to .NET 7. The `dotnet new` cli already supports it, but the Visual Studio support has not yet been started on.

Comment: Did you succeed? I followed the doc: VS 17.4.4 installed with .net 7 and can use "isEnabled" key within template.json but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I had tried it back in November, but from what I remember, it didn't work. Might be a good idea to ping Sayed on Twitter again. Maybe they delayed the Visual Studio inclusion.

Comment: Still not recognized in VS2022

Comment: @L4marr According to [another post](https://twitter.com/sayedihashimi/status/1693682654070137251) (somewhere within the replies of the original), they say there's no plans to introduce this to VS yet. lol

Comment: Very cool Microsoft

Comment: @L4marr Yup. :/